# Code returning ValueError for an exception, is this a syntax issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
while True :
    try:
        prompt = input('Enter a number: ')
        promptval = int(prompt)
        if prompt == 'done':
            break
            print("Maximum is ",max(promptval))
            print("Minimum is ",min(promptval))
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid input')
        continue
```

The prompt entry 'done' gives 'Invalid input'

Comment: You try to convert it to an int _before_ you check if it's `"done"`. `"done"` can't be converted to an int. Hence the ValueError.

Comment: @khelwood should I add another exception for 'done', instead of an 'if'? the code needs to validate entries that are integers, but also accept the only non-integer entry, which is 'done'?

Comment: You should just check if it's `"done"` *before* trying to convert it to an integer. (Outside the `try`/`except`)

Comment: Syntax issues usually lead to `SyntaxError`.